# Inserting a row in a tableview in a new section

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I start with a tableview with one section, the first section always has three rows. After some content has downloaded, I want show a new cell, in a second section, so I do :

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

But I get an NSInternalConsistencyException:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table
>   view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections
>   contained in the table view before the update (1), plus or minus the
>   number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

Why isn't it inserted the new section automatically, If I do insert a section, then I get problems when inserting rows that are not in new sections.

Why can't it just add the new section automatically? surely InsertRowAtIndexpath: also include inserting a section if necessary as an NSIndexPath also includes a section.

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.tableView insertSections:nsIndexSetToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

and don't forget to set numberOfSectionsInTavleView and numberOfRowsInSection accordingly.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSInteger numberOfSections;
    if (condition1) {
        numberOfSections = 2;
    } else if (condition2) {
        numberOfSections = 3;
    } else {
        numberOfSections = 4;
    }

    return numberOfSections;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section
    if(section == 1) return 3;
    else return numberOfRows;
}
```

Comment: I have done the first line of code, and rest is working as expected (else the exception wouldn't be thrown, at least not with the error given), and it works if I am inserting a row that needs a new section, but crashes if inserting a row into an existing section

Comment: Jonathan, what exactly do you mean "i have done the first line of code" and "rest is working as expected". basically, this answer is telling you that you are responsible for properly returninv values for numberOfSectionsInTableView: and tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: . if you insert a new section, then the former must properly return the new value, and if you insert a row in an existing section, then the latter must reflect that change. you must tie the data to the attempt to update the tableView.  is this what you meant "i have done the first line of code" and "rest is working as expected"?

Answer (score 0):

Keep this in ViewDidLoad

```
childArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Apple", @"Microsoft", @"HP", @"Cisco", nil];
childArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
parentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:childArray1, nil];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return [parentArray count];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      NSInteger rowCount ;
      if (section == 0)
      {
           rowCount = [childArray1 count];
      }
      else
      {
           rowCount = [childArray2 count];
      }
      return rowCount;
}
```

Once your content is downloaded from server.

```
 if([childArray2 count] > 0)
     [parentArray addObject : childArray2];
 [tableView reloadData];
```

This should work for you.