# Animating inserting a new row into a new section in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

The problem is quite simple.

I am attempting to animate the addition of a new row into a new section.

The update code:

```
func updateTableView(sessions: [Sessions]) {
   self.foundSessions = sessions
    if self.numberOfSections(in: self.tableView) == 0 {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertSections([0], with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    for i in 0..<self.foundSessions.count {
       self.tableView.beginUpdates()
       self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)], with: .automatic             
       self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

`UITableViewDataSource` code:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     if foundSessions.isEmpty { return 0 }
     return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return foundSessions.count
}
```

And the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert section 0 but there are only 0 sections after the update

Obviously, it seems the section is not getting inserted. If I take out `insertRows`, the empty section eventually shows up, as can be seen by the `tableFooterView` at the top. I have followed the advice of the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784268/inserting-a-row-in-a-tableview-in-a-new-section), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821088/how-to-dynamically-add-rows-to-a-specific-uitableview-section), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9482072/animate-the-insertion-of-a-new-section-in-uitableview), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706254/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-attempt-to-insert-row-0-into-section), and have read the respective [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW9) on the manner, obviously to no avail.

Any iOS gurus out there able to show me the error in my ways?

EDIT: More debugging info - `updateTableView` is called in the callback of an async function. I wrapped all this code in a `DispatchQueue.main.async` block in an attempt to remedy the situation, however, was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all your updates to section and it's row in one block, begin ... end like below

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.insertSections([0], with: .automatic)
for i in 0..<self.foundSessions.count {
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)], with: .automatic
}
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: that was my first attempt :/ should've written that. thanks for answering anyway!

Comment: I am not really sure why it is happening, but will put the actual reason soon.